# CSS: absolute and relative nested within relative, overlap

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to make a box in html/css (which divs within are relative to each other) where the read more hyperlink text (relative positioning), overlays the background image (Absolute). So that more text can be added in the description, the box instead of overlapping the image.

[Example of the current issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9yL3.jpg)

As you can see the description is ignoring the images position and overlapping.

Does anyone know how I'd go about making it so it pushes the read more and image below, instead of overlapping?

code for the html:

```
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-cont">
                <span class="content-type"></span>
                <h2 itemprop="name">Test limit thingTest limit thingTest limit thingTest limit thingTest..</h2>
                <p class="meta">By random name,  and random,  on 7 Random 2018</p>

                <p class="desc" itemprop="description">Look, just because I don't be givin' no man a foot massage don't make it right for Marsellus to throw Antwone into a glass ************' house, ******' up th
```

```
                <span class="img"><img src="/assets/image.jpg" alt="Screen bw"></span>

                <p class="cta"><span>+ read more</span></p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Code for the css:

```
box-wrap {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1e5373;
}

.section-boxes .box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

box p, .box h2, .box .content-type {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.box .img img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.section-boxes .box .cta {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```

This is what I managed to filter through actually controlling some/most the positioning in the boxes. The z-index for the description is higher which is why it's overlapping as with the read more box.

Comment: Share some code so someone can help you.

Comment: share your code

Comment: aavrug, I would love too, code is scattered across loads of different pages badly (I didn't write it), and even a vague answer that would point me in the right direction would be helpful right now, to be honest.

Comment: Hey there. What you'll want to do is give us the HTML and CSS that relates to the problem. (We don't want or need all of it) It's pretty much impossible to give you any help without knowing how it is currently set up.

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on your edit:
Modifications in CSS are commented below.

Then put `<p class="cta"><span>+ read more</span></p>` above `<div class="img"><img src="/assets/image.jpg" alt="Screen bw"></div>`.

You are also missing a closing `</p>` before opening `<p class="cta">`.

With this setup, `+read more` will overlap the background img but not the description (try to add more text to the description, you'll see it will push `+read more` and the background image down).

```css
box-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1e5373;
}
.cta {
  background: yellow;
}
.section-boxes .box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
box p,
.box h2,
.box .content-type {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.box .img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* add these, adjust margin as desired*/
  margin-top: -34px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.section-boxes .box .cta {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box boxed-">
  <div class="box-cont">
    <span class="content-type"></span>
    <h2 itemprop="name">Test limit thingTest limit thingTest limit thingTest limit thingTest..</h2>
    <p class="meta">By random name, and random, on 7 Random 2018</p>
    <p class="desc" itemprop="description">Look, just because I don't be givin' no man a foot massage don't make it right for Marsellus to throw Antwone into a glass ************' house, ******' up th</p>
    <p class="cta"><span>+ read more</span>
    </p>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="/assets/image.jpg" alt="Screen bw">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out and report back!

Comment: Hey Syden, it doesn't seem to do the trick, because I want Read more overlapping but not the description. I'll try to fiddle around with this, and report back once I find a solution and I'm determined to find one.